# Using checkbox to filter as table with a pipe

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Hi i have run into a problem when i wanted to filter my table with a checkbox.
I'm quite new to angular so i need help even with the most basic stuff.

the problem that happens is when i click on the check box it just filters the entire table.

here is my HTML :

```
     <form >
<input  type="checkbox"  name="reefer" [(ngModel)]="searchString" >reefer<br>
</form>

<!-- Container For Sale Table -->
 <table mdbTable>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let head of headElements" scope="col">{{head}} </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr mdbTableCol *ngFor="let c of characters | filter: {CID: searchString, Company:searchString,  Size: searchString, Type:searchString}; let i=index;">
      <th scope="row">{{c.CID}}</th>
      <td scope="row">{{c.Company}}</td>
      <td scope="row">{{c.Size}}</td>
      <td scope="row">{{c.Type}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my Pipe :

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
@Injectable()
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any, filter: any, defaultFilter: boolean): any {
    if (!filter){
      return items;
    }

    if (!Array.isArray(items)){
      return items;
    }

    if (filter && Array.isArray(items)) {
      let filterKeys = Object.keys(filter);

      if (defaultFilter) {
        return items.filter(item =>
            filterKeys.reduce((x, keyName) =>
                (x && new RegExp(filter[keyName], 'gi').test(item[keyName])) || filter[keyName] == "", true));
      }
      else {
        return items.filter(item => {
          return filterKeys.some((keyName) => {
            return new RegExp(filter[keyName], 'gi').test(item[keyName]) || filter[keyName] == "";
          });
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and this is my TS file for that component :

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-containers-page',
  templateUrl: './containers-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./containers-page.component.scss']
})
export class ContainersPageComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
  public searchString: string;
  public textSearch:string;

  characters = [
    {CID:'CIMU233921',Company:'ZIM',Size:'40',Type:'reefer'},
    {CID:'CIMU432434',Company:'ZIM',Size:'40',Type:'HQ'},
    {CID:'LRKU343222',Company:'ZIM',Size:'20',Type:'OT'},
    {CID:'LRKU343224',Company:'MSC',Size:'20',Type:'OT'},
    {CID:'DFJF334334',Company:'MSC',Size:'40',Type:'RG'},
    {CID:'VFJV344324',Company:'CHN',Size:'40',Type:'DR'}]


    headElements = ['CID', 'Company', 'Size', 'Type'];
}
```

I have tried replacing values in the NgModel.
I have tried changing the Value of the input.
I have tried to change the "name" value of the input even tho I'm not so sure what is that value for.

Thank you in advance

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz example?

Comment: can you elaborate i have never used stackblitz

Comment: [Do not user filtering pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe), especially with static data. Instead, implement the logic into the component itself.

Comment: This is not meant for static data. its just a mock until i get the Service from the guy who makes it.

Comment: @EliKnaffo  may be this will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56456222/how-to-filter-an-object-array-using-checkbox-with-angular/56458223#56458223

Comment: @JoelJoseph this didnt help me